# Can the Kindle SDK be used to read a book purchased on Amazon?

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

I would like to write an app that can read DRMed Kindle books. Is this possible?

Comment: their site says KDK is to create content, not to access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported for two reasons:

1. Kindle already has a way to read DRM content -- the bundled reader.
2. Amazon and its publishers would prefer only trusted applications read DRM content to keep the barrier high for breaking DRM.